# How can I loop through the JSON on Universal Windows Platform with C#

Tags: c#, json, foreach, uwp

I am developing an app on UWP.

When I connect with a server api and I get the next response I don't have problems.

```
{"value":"Login successfull","sessionId":"a95077855b05ed0fec5d7fa3abafa126e15aba2a"}
```

I can get information in the following way:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonString);
string token = jsonObject["sessionId"].GetString();
string value = jsonObject["value"].GetString();
```

but my problem is when i get the next response of the api:

```
[{"person":{"name":"name1","country":"Spain","city":"user_city","phone":null}},{"person":{"name":"name2","country":"Turkey","city":"user_city","phone":"1111111"}},{"person":{"name":"name3","country":"Argentina","city":"user_city","phone":"22222"}},{"person":{"name":"name4","country":"Argentina","city":"user_city","phone":"33333"}}]
```

How can I loop through the JSON and get all the people that match a condition?

I have to do with "Windows.Data.Json"

Comment: Can you please post your full JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If interested in a solution using only [`Windows.Data.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Data.Json) namespace, here it is:

```
var rootValue = JsonValue.Parse(jsonString);
foreach (var item in rootValue.GetArray())
{
    var unamedObject = item.GetObject();
    var personObject = unamedObject["person"].GetObject();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(personObject["name"].GetString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(personObject["country"].GetString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(personObject["city"].GetString());
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(personObject["phone"].GetString());
}
```

**Why would somebody pick Windows.Data.Json over Newtonsoft's  Json.net?**

If your JSON needs are simple, you can reduce the size of your app ~1 MB by choosing `Windows.Data.Json` because it is part of the operating system.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code works perfect. I need to use System.Data.Json because is an order from my boss (it is a big problem). Thank you!

Comment: Well the big advantage of Json.net is that it will do the mapping in one go, so you don't need to remap if you want to use model classes

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you try out Json.net nuget package and deserialise the json payload to classes through that.

A good tutorial can be found here: http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/general/deserialize-json-data-using-newtonsoft-json-net-library/

But if you search you'll find more.

In short, you first copy paste your json and use Visual Studio > File > Paste Special > To paste to classes ( first open an empty cs file and set your cursor inside it ).

After that you use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>()` to actually parse the json string.
Once parsed you'll have an array of items if your original json also defined an array.

Note RootObject is the first class object in the generated classes in Visual Studio

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to use this library. I needed to do it with "Windows.Data.Json" but I will follow your advice! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do it without external libraries, if that is the real reason for the stipulation of Windows.Data.Json.

I'd likely do it something like this...

First I'd make some classes representing the returning JSON:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Person person { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
}
```

Then add a little method to deserialize:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json);
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
```

And finally deserialize and query that result like so:

```
    var persons = Json.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(textBox.Text);

    var peeps = (from p in persons
                where p.person.name.StartsWith("name")
                select p).ToList();
```